# From where is it better to import a js file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, import

I would like to know which solution is the fastest and the best for my web pages between importing a javascript file from an external source and internally. Which pro and cons for each solution.
For example, which one is the best:

```
 < script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

or

```
< script type="text/javascript" src="../jquery.js"></script>
```

(same for json2.js)

I could not find any tips on google

Thanks!

Comment: Biggest con of a CDN is that it probably doesn't have `fonctions.js`.

Comment: Sorry I meant jquery.js, was a mistake!

Comment: It's interesting how many answers omit geographical location from their answers (only one answer talks about it, +1 @eureka). The physical distance that the data has to travel can be dramatically minimized by using a CDN since the data on the CDN is spread-out in data centers around the world.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main benefit of using a CDN (Content Delivery Network) is that given their widespread use, the chances are your visitor may already have a cached copy of the script you're trying to load on their browser. This will completely negate any loading time. If they don't have a cached copy, the chances are the CDN would deliver it to them faster than your server could anyway. In my opinion it's best to use a CDN where possible.

Even with that in mind, CDN aren't infallible, and you don't want your site to rely 100% on someone else's server. I'd advise on having a local copy of your scripts and use those as a backup where possible. For jQuery, this is quite easy:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    if (typeof jQuery == 'undefined') {
        document.write(unescape("%3Cscript src='/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js' type='text/javascript'%3E%3C/script%3E"));
    }
</script>
```

Other libraries may vary in their methods for testing if they're loaded, but the idea is the same.

**It's also worth noting that if you are loading from Google's CDN ALWAYS use the full version number otherwise the script will not be cached.**

That is to say if your request URL looks like this:

```
"http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js" // highest 1.4 version (1.4.4)
"http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js" // latest version (1.7.1)
```

The expires header is set previous to the current date, so the effect of caching is nullified.

[More info on this here](http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js)

Answer (score 3):

The fastest is definetely from your own server, at least in most cases(that is in pure download speed).
However, there is a much greater chance that a visitor has Google's version of jQuery already cached in their browser from visiting another site using the same library, and as such it probably makes more sense using the Google API for the most common libraries, as that would be much faster if the library is cached compared to having to download it from your server.

Also, these days you can do this, and request the version by just using the first number :

```
http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js
```

And automagicly get the latest version ;)

Comment: Why is it "definitely faster" from your own server?

Comment: If your server is in Iceland and your user is in Australia, it'll probably be faster to use Google's CDN since their data centers are spread out all around the world. I believe this is the strongest argument for using a CDN. Although if your server isn't configured to properly send expiration headers and compress it's output then a CDN would be a great idea (compression is huge).

Comment: I agree, a CDN is great in most cases, but Google's is'nt really that fast, and my shared accounts will send a file faster than Google will these days, and my dedicated server will send a file a lot faster than Google on even one of their good days. At least where I live, Google's servers seems to be slowing down each and every day, probably from to many users requesting to much data. That's why atleast for me, and most of the webmaster I know, downloading from Google is slower, could be different other places, but because of the caching benefits, we all use Google anyway.

Comment: That may be the case with Google, since they're providing a free service, and as a result, may not invest an appropriate amount of servers/upstream to get super-fast downloads, but if you're using something like AWS or Akamai, etc., it'll beat your server any day of the week and twice on Sunday.

Answer (score 3):

If you import javascript from `http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js`improve data access, Google has CDN that means deliver content more efficiently to users (depend on their location).

Read more about CDN:http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html

Answer (score 2):

Using a [CDN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_delivery_network) has some advantages:

- If the user has already visited another site that uses the same script from the same location, they may have it in the browser cache already. The page loading speeds up when they don't have to re-download it.
- The CDN provider probably has the server set up to maximize the efficiency of serving the scripts, for example by sending the file from a server physically closes to the user.
- You save bandwidth.

The disadvantages:

- You are dependent on the service provider: if their service is down, your site breaks. (This can be helped by serving a local copy of the file if the external script couldn't be loaded.)
- You have to trust the service provider for serving the correct file and nothing malicious.

Answer (score 0):

If it is some known resource like googlePlusOne or another stable web service (or external ad), it is better to use external link. This way it will always be up to date.
If it is a library js (like jQuery or Ext) it is better to download the source.

Answer (score 0):

Loading libraries from a local repository will always be faster which would suggest that local is always better, however... Loading libraries from external sources, for example jQuery, will allow your site to always load the most up to date version of the library.

Comment: Why is it "always faster" from your own server?